# Basic inequality between moments of random variables

Tags: inequality, random-variables

Is it ever the case that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}\leq \mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]
\end{align*}
for any two random variables $X$ and $Y$? Assume that all relevant moments exists and are finite.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, e.g. when $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=0$.

Comment: Take any $X, Y$ with say unit variance and mean $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just an inequality about numbers. If $a,b>0$, then $$\sqrt{ab} \le a + b$$ as you can see by squaring the inequality:
$$
ab \le (a+b)^2.
$$
This last one holds simply because the right-hand side equals $a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$, which is greater than $ab$.